# Static variable doesn't initialize to given value

Tags: c, embedded, static-variables, variable-initialization

I have a **static** "init" variable to run a function once on startup, *(RTOS)* but it seems to initialize to a random value. If I remove the **static** tag, everything works great. *(Except for the obvious issue of it running the init function every pass.)* Could anyone give more insight as to why this isn't working or perhaps a better way to achieve this?

Example code:

```
void ManageStructures()
{
    // Variable declarations/definitions
    static uint8_t StructInitialized;
    // Have also tried "static uint8_t StructInitialized = 0", neither worked

    // Function prototypes
    void InitStruct();

    if (!StructInitialized)
    {
        StructInitialized= 1;
        InitStruct();
    }
    Test = StructInitialized;
```

**edit**: I apologize for the lack of information. This is for a company and I am trying to stay within the bounds of our public information policy. The MCU is a STM32F7 series using the "Ac6 STM32 MCU GCC" toolchain. I am not well versed in compiler operations so it may take me longer to find answers to the compiler or makefile related questions.

**edit**: It has become clear that this is an issue with the compiler or linker scripts and not my code. That being said, it has also become abundantly clear that I need to learn more about toolchains, linker scripts, and compilers in general before getting to the root of this issue. I'll return to this question once I have become familiar enough to give valuable feedback or answer it myself. Thank you everyone for the feedback and direction!

Comment: That code would work in a standard environment. Your RTOS might not properly initialize the relevant data sections of your program when it starts up (e.g. forgetting to zero out the .bss section is a frequent issue when dealing with low level RTOS, or bare metal programming) leaving your static variable with whatever garbage was at that location in memory. Another issue could be the memory map of your program+rtos is not corret.

Comment: _but it seems to initialize to a random value_. It should be 0, otherwise your compiler is broken

Comment: Why is there a function prototype inside of a function?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons why not?

Comment: Aside the already mentioned specific compiler issues, there is another possible cause. Static variables are all stored somewhere in data segment (in BSS if not initialized or initialized to 0). If your variable is placed near an array and it is wrongly accessed (out of bounds) it might happen that your variable is someway overwritten.

Comment: ... and that is why we generally want a [mre] to refer to.  No reason is *evident* for the code fragment presented to exhibit the behavior described, but we don't have enough information to evaluate the possibility of the program overall having UB.

Comment: To get to the bottom of this, you need to specify which MCU & tool chain you are using.

Comment: this is a bootstrap thing which isnt related to toolchain nor mcu it is related to the bootstrap/c library but sometimes the C library bootstrap isnt used.  could also be linker script related since that has an intimate relationship with the bootstrap.  we need to see the bootstrap and the address spaces for .bss and .data.

Comment: if you were to build a project  unsigned int x = 5;, unsigned int y;  int main ( void ) { return 0; }  would you be able to post the disassembly of the bootstrap for that?  that would tell us everything we need to know.

Comment: Could please you clarify which files you are referring to by "bootstrap"? I'm trying to learn, but I don't know compilers that well and this one was set up by a partner company that we are no longer in contact with.

Comment: @old_timer When dealing with embedded systems, the standard lib as well as the start-up code is delivered by the tool chain. Most often something proprietary, rather than Glibc etc. Hence MCU & tool chain does matter, since the lib will (hopefully) be optimized for the specific MCU.

Comment: After the edit: So it's some Eclipse junk. What happens if you create a new project in the same Eclipse IDE for the target MCU? Do you get a question about "minimal" or "standard/ANSI" etc upon project creation? Most Eclipse ports for ARM tend to have something like that.

Comment: The 'startup\startup_stm32.s' and 'LinkerScript.ld' files created for a new project for STM32F7 in System Workbench for STM32 seem to do the right thing. Perhaps the linker script and startup code for your RTOS do something strange.

Comment: @Lundin that is not part of a toolchain a toolchain is tools (compiler, assembler, linker) when you add the library and often an ide, etc, it becomes something else.  but I guess the term is subject to interpretation, the library is where the startup code woudl be not the tools so it is easier to talk about the library not the tools.  your answer though covers the real problem and if I could upvote it more than once I would as that is clearly where the problem lies

Comment: @old_timer Tool chain = the tools. Including debugger software + ICD adapter, IDE, version control, static analyser etc etc. And when a compiler vendor speak of target support of an embedded system, it doesn't just mean the raw machine code generation, but also CRT and linker memory map. Often delivered together with IDE,debugger customization for the target, drivers for ICD and so on.

Comment: almost all 'bare metal' system have a first executed program (usually called `start.s`) that needs to be the first object file in the linker command file.  This `start` file is what clears the necessary areas of memory to 0x00`

Comment: @Lundin again I disagree, we have to agree to disagree on this, toolchain is a chain of tools, compiler assembler linker.    libraries both C and board/part specific are added to the toolchain as well as the debugger and any GUI, they are not links in the (tool)chain.  If what you are saying is the case then this is definitely the wrong forum for asking questions, the op would be asking ST as this is a tech support question since what you are talking about is a complete deliverable product from a vendor.  and SO is not a product support platform. same for most of the other questions here

Comment: to get the development environment you take for example the gnu toolchain then you add libraries and an IDE/environment to it.  the whole package is not a toolchain the toolchain is just one set of components.  The term SDK is often used but that is up to marketing as to what to call it once bundled.  IDE is another name often used.

Comment: when I sudo apt-get -y install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi
I have a complete toolchain, but then I have to add any libraries including bootstrap

Answer (score 8):

It is common that embedded systems run with a "minimal startup" code, meaning that they never initialize `.bss` or `.data` during start-up. Meaning that if you write something like `static int foo = 42;`, the code will compile but the variable will never be set.

This isn't standard C compilant, so usually upon project creation you get an option from the IDE to have a "minimal" or "standard" startup.

This likely lies in the so-called "CRT" (C run-time) delivered with your tool chain and not in the RTOS. If you single step your program from where it actually starts (the reset vector) rather than from where main() starts, you'll be able to see exactly what the CRT does and doesn't.

Unfortunately debuggers often use a "dumbed-down mode", since embedded systems programmers are by default assumed to be completely incompetent nowadays. Meaning that they silently insert a breakpoint at main() and run until that point. You might have to "un-dumb" your debugger in order to debug the CRT.